# How to create HTML element for JavaScript and not for HTML

Tags: javascript

**I have this simplified code:**

```js
const chancesData = ["facebook","twitter","google"];
        let inputsArr = [];
        const inputsArrFill = chancesData.map((cur, index) => {
          const input = (document.createElement("input").value =
            chancesData[index]);
          inputsArr.push(input); //I want the pushed value to be something like this "<input value"facebook">"
          return inputsArr;
          //so the returned array (should) be something like this: 
          //["<input value"facebook">","<input value"twitter">","<input value"google">"]
        });
        console.dir(inputsArrFill);
```

as you can see if you opened this coed in your console, the returned array looks like this:

```
['facebook', 'twiiter', 'google']
```

I want it to look like this:

```
['<input value="facebook">','<input value="twitter">','<input value="google">']
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `setAttribute` to put the value into the HTML markup, then retrieve it with `outerHTML`:

```js
const chancesData = ["facebook", "twitter", "google"];
const inputsArrFill = chancesData.map(str => {
  const input = document.createElement("input");
  input.setAttribute('value', str);
  return input.outerHTML;
});
console.dir(inputsArrFill);
```

But it'd be easier to use ordinary string concatenation:

```js
const chancesData = ["facebook", "twitter", "google"];
const inputsArrFill = chancesData.map(str => `<input value="${str}">`);
console.dir(inputsArrFill);
```

Comment: Why you're using setAttribute instead of .value ?

Comment: Because just setting the `.value` won't be reflected in the HTML markup which `.outerHTML` retrieves (just like typing into an input field doesn't change the HTML markup - it only changes the state of the element)

Answer (score 3):

The result of an assignment expression, is the assigned value. With

> ```
> const input = (document.createElement("input").value =
>         chancesData[index]);
> ```

you did not store a reference to the created HTML element into your variable, you stored the assigned value, `chancesData[index]`.

You need to do these two things in separate steps.

```js
const chancesData = ["facebook","twitter","google"];
        let inputsArr = [];
        const inputsArrFill = chancesData.map((cur, index) => {
          const input = document.createElement("input");
          input.value = chancesData[index];           
            
          inputsArr.push(input); //I want the pushed value to be something like this "<input value"facebook">"
          return inputsArr;
          //so the returned array (should) be something like this: 
          //["<input value"facebook">","<input value"twitter">","<input value"google">"]
        });
        console.dir(inputsArrFill);
```

But if you really want `<input value="facebook">` as a result, then you will probably have to push that in string form to begin with. You have little control over how an HTML element object gets *displayed* by the console.

Comment: Thanks a lot "The result of an assignment expression, is the assigned value."

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code.

```js
(function createHTMlString() {
  const chancesData = ["facebook", "twitter", "google"];
  var outputObj = []
  for (var i = 0; i < chancesData.length; i++) {
  var inputTag = document.createElement("INPUT");
    inputTag.setAttribute("value", chancesData[i]);    
    outputObj.push(inputTag);
  }
  console.log(outputObj)
})();
```